# How to get the census block corresponding to coordinate (longitude, latitude)?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, latitude-longitude, census

I have a shapefile containing the census blocks of my region and a list of "points" (longitude and latitude).
For every point, I need to associate the census block where the point is inside.

I followed the instructions of Vale. Now I see in QGIS my "points" and the census blocks of my region. My points correctly appear to be inside their census blocks, but when I use the tool "Join attributes by location", it warns me that the reference systems of the vectors are not the same. In fact:

- the shapefile of my region is "EPGS:32632, WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N"
- the points are "EPGS:4326, WGS 84"

and the join fails. How can I do?

P.S. I got the points' coordinates from Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

A spatial join is what you are looking for.

In QGIS:

```
Vector -> Data management tool > Join attributes by location
```

The Target vector layer is the one you want to add the attributes to (your points).

The Join vector will be your census block